# ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME when load text file using fileprovider

Tags: android, android-fileprovider

**Provider in manifest.xml**

```
<!-- File Provider -->
    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.example.test.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
    </provider>
```

**Resource file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

**Use of fileprovider**

```
Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".fileprovider", file);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "*/*");
intent.startActivity(intent);
```

**Reference** : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38200282/android-os-fileuriexposedexception-file-storage-emulated-0-test-txt-exposed/40674771?noredirect=1)

**Description** :
I can't open image, text file, pdf using this file provider.
When i open the file text file its give me ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME.
If i open image or pdf its nothing show anything

Comment: Please tell the value of uri.toString().

Comment: And file.getAbsolutePath().

Comment: /storage/emulated/0/KOOPSv3Sales/KOOPSv3Sales Message Attachment/29ca8aed.txt

Comment: content://com.example.test.fileprovider/external_files/KOOPSv3Sales/KOOPSv3Sales Message Attachment/29ca8aed.txt could not be loaded because ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

Comment: Can you open the file yourself with getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri) ? And file.exists() returns true?

Comment: `When i open the file text file`. Unclear. You are not opening it i think. Nor your app. But an app the user chooses from the list. So the message is from that app. Try other apps. Maybe the app you choosed does not know about content:// schemes.

Comment: ` If i open image or pdf its nothing show anything`. You should mention the apps the user choosed. And Android version.

Comment: ohk i will check in another device

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the "FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION" flag to your intent:

```
Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".fileprovider", file);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "*/*");
intent.addFlags(FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
intent.startActivity(intent);
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION

> FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION If set, the recipient of this Intent
>   will be granted permission to perform read operations on the URI in
>   the Intent's data and any URIs specified in its ClipData. When
>   applying to an Intent's ClipData, all URIs as well as recursive
>   traversals through data or other ClipData in Intent items will be
>   granted; only the grant flags of the top-level Intent are used.

Comment: Nice, this solved it in my case. It is weird, since I thought the `grantUriPermissions` in the manifest for the provider would be sufficient.